# How to create an index that shows which line a word is on, preferably using enumerate?

Tags: numbers, line, cpu-word, enumerate

```
filename= input('please give name of file', )
lines= open(filename).readlines()
for i,line in enumerate(lines,start=1,):
        print(str(i),str(line))
```

## i've numbered the lines of the text document

## How do i create another index which shows each word and on which line it appears?

## it should look like this:

## numbered lines in text document below:

1)test
2)this 
3)this
4)this
5)dog
6)dog
7)cat
8)cat
9)hamster
10)hamster

# i'm struggling to make this output:

index:

```
this           [2,3,4]
test           [1]
dog            [5,6]
cat            [7,8]
hamster        [9,10]
```

Comment: Are the line numbers contained in the text document, or just illustrative?

Comment: the numbers (which represent line numbers) should be contained in the text document.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for a [*dictionary*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), where you can store the line numbers for each word easily:

```
index = dict()
for i, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
    if not line in index: index[line] = []
    index[line].append(i)
for word in index: print(word.strip(), index[word], sep='\t')
```

> the numbers (which represent line numbers) should be contained in the text document.

In this case we have to separate the number from the word:

```
index = dict()
for line in lines:
    i, word = line.strip().split(')')
    if not word in index: index[word] = []
    index[word].append(int(i))
for word in index: print(word, index[word], sep='\t')
```